# not able to create spree rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spree

I am trying to create a rails spree app.

I am following this [official](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html) link.

When I do `spree install --auto-accept`, I am getting the below error.

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
>     In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
>       rails (= 4.2.0)
>
> In Gemfile:
>       rails (= 4.2.0)
>
> ```
> spree (~> 3.0.8) was resolved to 3.0.8, which depends on
>   spree_core (= 3.0.8) was resolved to 3.0.8, which depends on
>     rails (~> 4.2.2)
> ```
>
> Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using
>   only the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

And then when I run `bundle update`, I am getting below error.

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
>     In Gemfile:
>       rails (= 4.2.0)
>       spree (~> 3.0.8) was resolved to 3.0.8, which depends on
>         spree_core (= 3.0.8) was resolved to 3.0.8, which depends on
>           rails (~> 4.2.2)

So I am not able to solve this dependency error.

Please help with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, I had the same issue. Documentation is a bit outdated.
Please repeat installation process installing version 4.2.2 of Rails instead of 4.2.0:

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.2
gem install bundler
gem install spree_cmd
rails _4.2.2_ new mystore
cd mystore
spree install --auto-accept
```

I just checked and it works.

Comment: Oh yes, It works. It's a shame I didn't try this earlier..

Thanks